# Starting Samsung Galaxy Gear App automatically in Background after reboot

Tags: background-process, tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

I want to write an app on my Samsung Galaxy Gear that starts automatically in background after rebooting.

Therefore I want to write an native tizen app.

I've read much about this topic on other websites but every answer is different. I've read something about, that the possibility to run automatically an app in background after reboot was disabled due security reasons. But there should exist a workaround with the alarm-api, that can do the trick.

But is the use of the alarm-api really the only option to start my Tizen App automatically in Background after reboot? And if yes, what disadvantages has the alarm-api?

I've read something about, that the alarm api must be used in an tizen Web-Application and therefore it works only with an app on the foreground in combination with an native app. Is that true? If yes, is it then possible to start the app automatically in background without launching the app in foreground?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can find similar issue and answer in this [page](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/native-application-development/wearable-start-service-application-restart).

If you don't care about the battery consumption, you can use Alarm API.
For Native API use, read this [page](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/alarm-and-scheduling/alarm#scenario_3).